# Slim 3 - getParsedBody() Incorrect integer value: 'NULL'

Tags: php, mysql, rest, pdo, slim

This is my first attempt on Slim 3. I am trying to make a simple web application, but whenever I am trying to retrieve a NULL/Empty request parameter it's always a string, and trying to save the value into a numeric column will result in

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'last_login' at row 1

Validating each parameter seems like an exhausting task. I would like to know if that's my only option or there's something I'm missing.

I also had some issues trying to save an object with private fields into the database, so I would really appreciate any comments on my approach.

**Table Design**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
```

---

**User Model**

```
class User implements JsonSerializable
{

    private $user_id;
    private $name;
    private $last_login;

    public function __construct($user_id = null, $name = null, $last_login = null)
    {
        if ($user_id !== null) $this->user_id = $user_id;
        if ($name !== null) $this->name = $name;
        if ($last_login !== null) $this->last_login = $last_login;
    }

    /**
     *  Getters and setters
     */

    function jsonSerialize()
    {

        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

---

**UserDAO**

```
class UserDAO
{

    public function addUser(User $user)
    {

        $query = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . TABLE_USERS . ' VALUE (:user_id, :name, :last_login)');
        $result = $query->execute((array)$user->jsonSerialize());

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Not calling jsonSerialize() on execute will result in

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined

I assume PDO can't access model's private fields, I could be wrong tho.

---

**Routes**

```
$app->post('/user/add', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    $input = $request->getParsedBody();

    $userDAO = new UserDAO();

    $id = $input['user_id'];
    $name = $input['name'];
    $last = $input['last_login'];

    // Set ID as NULL to show the difference dump between ID and Last_login
    $user = new User(null, $name, $last);

    var_dump($input);
    var_dump($user);

    $userDAO->addUser($user);
});
```

---

**Dump Result**

```
C:\wamp64\www\Rest\app\core\Routes.php:61:
array (size=3)
  'user_id' => string 'NULL' (length=4)
  'name' => string 'B' (length=1)
  'last_login' => string 'NULL' (length=4)

C:\wamp64\www\Rest\app\core\Routes.php:62:
object(User)[59]
  private 'user_id' => null
  private 'name' => string 'B' (length=1)
  private 'last_login' => string 'NULL' (length=4)
```

I guess that's the whole issue, how to turn this **string 'NULL'** into **NULL** in an efficient way.

---

The insert method works just fine after adding jsonSerialize() on excute. Tried calling addUser() from index.php and data get inserted into database.

Sorry for the long post, but I've tried to remove a lot of fields for simplicity without leaving any relative code out.

Comment: Show the actual curl request you are doing. It sounds like you are sending string value of "NULL" instead of null.

Comment: @MikaTuupola This being handled by PhpStorm rest tool or Postman(Chrome extension). Basically fields to fill, and as Rob mentioned in his reply it will always come as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data in the Request object are strings. Hence, if it's string `"NULL"` you need to manually convert it to `null`.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to stop inserting `user_id` as it's an auto increment field. i.e. the correct SQL statement to prepare is:

```
$query = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . TABLE_USERS 
    . ' (name, last_login) VALUE (:name, :last_login)');
```

Comment: I just thought there must be an easier way to deal with this, beside manually converting all fields. Specially on a large number of fields and having to do it individually as well.  

As for the `user_id` I kept it there just for testing purposes. I have too many null-able numeric fields in a lot of tables, inserting `"NULL"` into them is a problem obviously.

Comment: Use a filtering and validation library such as zend-inputfilter and create a `"NULL"` to `null` filter for it?

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but that was actually very helpful so I am marking it as an answer.